# Corel Draw X8 text in table wrong direction?

Tags: text, corel-draw, tables

I'm using Corel Draw X8 and I want to create a table with 3 columns and a bunch of rows. But as soon as I click inside the table, as well as when I type something in any of the table cells, the text is written automatically in the downward direction, with the bottom of the text facing left (in other words, as if normal text got rotated 90 degrees clockwise).

When I change the text orientation, the text becomes upside down. How do I make all cells have normal horizontal text?

Answer (score 1):

Select the table by clicking on its edge. Open the Window menu and select Text > Text Properties.

In Text Properties change the text alignment from Align right to Align left (in Paragraph).

Under Frame you can also find the control for the Vertical alignment.